# git remote branch checkout

Tags: git, github, version-control

I create new repository on `github` and made few commits, according to `github` web interface, my repository has two branches `master` and `HEAD`, when I switch from `master` to `HEAD`, I'm seeing my files.

I'd like to get checkout of `HEAD` on my local drive:

```
[alexus@j ~]$ git clone https://github.com/a1exus/jt4cb.git
Cloning into 'jt4cb'...
remote: Counting objects: 32, done.
remote: Total 32 (delta 5), reused 5 (delta 5), pack-reused 26
Unpacking objects: 100% (32/32), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[alexus@j ~]$ cd jt4cb/
[alexus@j ~/jt4cb]$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
[alexus@j ~/jt4cb]$ ls
README.md
[alexus@j ~/jt4cb]$
```

How do I get to my files from my local checkout?

Please advise.

*** UPDATE ***

I updated my question with better wording to explain my actual issue and end goal.

Answer (score 0):

HEAD is a pointer to the tip of your branch.  Right now, it's pointing to the tip of master.

If you want that, just check out your master branch.

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such concept in Git as the remote branch `HEAD` as far as I know.  `HEAD` is simply the tip of the current branch or commit where you are.

Git uses remote tracking branches to bridge between your local Git setup and what is happening with the actual remote branches.  In your case, there is a tracking branch called `origin/master` which tracks the remote `master` branch.  The command `git fetch` is what updates your remote tracking branch.  If you want to point your `HEAD` to the remote `master` branch, the following commands, which you were already doing, will accomplish this:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

After this, your local `master` will be in sync with the remote.  If you ever want to see the difference between the remote `master` and your local one without actually updating your local `master`, you can try the following:

```
git fetch
git diff master origin/master
```

Another option to "test drive" the remote `master` would be to create a temporary local branch:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b temp_master origin/master
```

You can explore the temporary branch, and then delete it once you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

#### `master` is a branch, `HEAD` is a pointer to top commit in current branch

From git [checkout doc](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-checkout), you will see

> The git checkout command serves three distinct functions: checking out
>   files, checking out commits, and checking out branches. In this
>   module, we’re only concerned with the first two configurations.

I would highly recommend you to read the full doc.

```
git checkout master
```

Return to the master branch. Branches are covered in depth in the next module, but for now, you can just think of this as a way to get back to the “current” state of the project.

```
git checkout <commit>
git checkout HEAD
```

Update all files in the working directory to match the specified commit. You can use either a commit hash or a tag as the `<commit>` argument. This will put you in a detached `HEAD` state.

You can use `HEAD` which will point to the last commit.